# Decoding string in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have the following string:

```
u"examined by other children\u2014particularly the children of George MacDonald."
```

but I can't find a way to decode it. What encoder/decoder do I need for python. There are also lots of "\n\nOn" leading \n which I'd like to remove. I've tried string.decode("utf-8")

> TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Edit:

This is within the larger paragraph from Alice in Wonderland from wikipedia:

> u'BackgroundAlice was published in 1865, three years after the
>   Reverend Charles Lutwidge Dodgson and the Reverend Robinson Duckworth
>   rowed in a boat, on 4 July 1862, [4] up the Isis with the three young
>   daughters of Henry Liddell (the Vice-Chancellor of Oxford University
>   and Dean of Christ Church): Lorina Charlotte Liddell (aged 13, born
>   1849) ("Prima" in the book\'s prefatory verse); Alice Pleasance
>   Liddell (aged 10, born 1852) ("Secunda" in the prefatory verse); Edith
>   Mary Liddell (aged 8, born 1853) ("Tertia" in the prefatory verse).
>   [5]\n\nThe journey began at Folly Bridge near Oxford and ended five
>   miles away in the village of Godstow. During the trip the Reverend
>   Dodgson told the girls a story that featured a bored little girl named
>   Alice who goes looking for an adventure. The girls loved it, and Alice
>   Liddell asked Dodgson to write it down for her. He began writing the
>   manuscript of the story the next day, although that earliest version
>   no longer exists. The girls and Dodgson took another boat trip a month
>   later when he elaborated the plot to the story of Alice, and in
>   November he began working on the manuscript in earnest. [6]\n\nTo add
>   the finishing touches he researched natural history for the animals
>   presented in the book, and then had the book examined by other
>   children\u2014particularly the children of George MacDonald. He added
>   his own illustrations but approached John Tenniel to illustrate the
>   book for publication, telling him that the story had been well liked
>   by children. [6]\n\nOn 26 November 1864 he gave Alice the handwritten
>   manuscript of Alice\'s Adventures Under Ground, with illustrations by
>   Dodgson himself, dedicating it as "A Christmas Gift to a Dear Child in
>   Memory of a Summer\'s Day". [7] Some, including Martin Gardner,
>   speculate there was an earlier version that was destroyed later by
>   Dodgson when he wrote a more elaborate copy by hand. [8]\n\nBut before
>   Alice received her copy, Dodgson was already preparing it for
>   publication and expanding the 15,500-word original to 27,500 words,
>   [9] most notably adding the episodes about the Cheshire Cat and the
>   Mad Tea-Party.'

I want to have this in plain text which can be parsed over. I get the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in
>   position 1295: ordinal not in range(128)

when I try paragraph.decode("unicode_escape") or paragraph."string_escape").

Comment: there is no problem with your text, that I can put in a variable and print out directly. and `print s.replace('\n\n', '\n')` works also perfectly for me. So can you tell more about the exact commands you're trying to issue? and what is your python version? what is your os? and what locale environment are you using?

Comment: OP's smaller example was missing the `u` of the larger example.  His input string is already Unicode.  I fixed the smaller string.

Comment: I am using OSX 10.7.5, ipython 0.12.1 and the pattern library in particular, their example: http://tinyurl.com/m2qe6ag on Xterm 2.6.5

Answer (score 0):

It's already Unicode, hence the `u` at the start of the string.  You only `decode` byte strings. `\u2014` is just the Unicode character for the `EM DASH` and you are displaying the `repr()` of the string.  `print` the string and you'll likely see the `EM DASH` if you're console supports it.  Printing automatically *encodes* the Unicode string in the console encoding.  Here I've switched my Windows console to a code page that supports an em dash (the default cp437 doesn't):

```
C:>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x=u"examined by other children\u2014particularly the children of George MacDonald."
>>> print x
examined by other children—particularly the children of George MacDonald.
```